# How to perform "find" command with another embedded command in another directory?

Tags: batch-file, window, dos

I would like to write a function which is to perform "find" command with another embedded command, %recent% in another directory(share drive).

Below is the idea:

```
REM Take in log file name input eg. "result_10030" = %1 to search for all result_10030*.log = %1*.log
REM Use the following to list the files matching result_10030*.log

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /d /od /b %1*.log') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%

REM Use %recent% as the file to perform find
REM Take in %2 as share drive path

find "PASSED" %2%recent%
```

Apparently it is not working.

Your advice will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: This looks like a Windows batch file - not related to DOS, C#, python.net, or window (the GUI thing, not the OS). Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DIR `/D` and `/B` options are not compatible - the `/B` option overrides the `/D` option.

Your FOR /F loop also needs to know what path to look in, not just your FIND commnad. The simplest thing to do is change your current directory to your desired path.

```
pushd %2
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /d /od /b "%~1*.log"') do set "recent=%%x"
echo %recent%
find "PASSED" "%recent%"
set rtn=%errorlevel%
popd
exit /b %rtn%
```

Comment: i tried to remove the /D and it would not affect the function. i also tried out the /o-d and /od, it is just the arrangement of the 1st file and last file. I need that /od is to get the last file.

Comment: Actually my plan is to create a batch file for this function. this batch file is able to get the last file and perform the find "PASSED" %recent%, provided all the files in the same directory with the batch file. But the problem is i need to perform this function in other directory. that is why i came out with this idea find "PASSED" %2%recent%. %2 is the path where the files/results stored at.

Comment: @user1618511 - Oops - I was confusing /od with /ad. I understand what you are attempting now. Check out my revised answer.

Comment: hey dude, thanks!!! it is working. but is that another method without changing the original directory to the particular directory as this will cause my automation flow stop working.

Comment: @user1618511 - Sure, you can put the path prefix in both the DIR and FIND statements. But another option is to simply POPD after the FIND completes to return to your original location.

Comment: but my FIND need to be the last command as the errorlevel code return 0 will tell the automation update pass in status and 1 is fail in status. If put POPD after the FIND will just return code 0 and automation will just update pass result to the database even though the result itself is failing. :)

Comment: Then save the errorlevel before POPD and then EXIT /B with saved errorlevel. See my updated answer.

Comment: really thanks for your help~ my automation flow is working fine with your solution provided. =）